# PHP: Create JSON data for JS autocomplete from Database

Tags: php, json, autocomplete

I wish to prepare the JSON data and send to jquery autocomplete made by [devbridge](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete), it want the data be format as this scheme:

```
{
    "suggestions": [
        { "value": "United Arab Emirates", "data": "AE" },
        { "value": "United Kingdom",       "data": "UK" },
        { "value": "United States",        "data": "US" }
    ]
}
```

So I'm trying to get the data from database and put in an array.

```
<?php
include '../core/config.php';
include '../core/db.class.php';

$DB->query("SELECT * FROM `prodotti`;");
$prodotti = $DB->fetchAll();

class json_prodotti {
    public $suggestions = '';
}
class json_suggestions {
    public $value = '';
    public $data = '';
    public $price = '';
}

$j = new json_prodotti;
$s = new json_suggestions;
$a = array();

foreach ($prodotti as $prd ) {
    $s->value = $prd['name'];
    $s->data  = $prd['ID'];
    $s->price = $prd['price'];
    array_push($a,$s);
}


$j->suggestions = $a;


echo json_encode($j);

?>
```

As you can see I'm using a database class, this work as expected and I'm using it in other parts of project. Here is the function fetchAll() that is called to fetch the data, the __construct is working fine.

```
public function fetchAll(){
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

Something is wrong in my code, I got the JSON as expected, but the foreach cycle repeat the same database row as many rows I got in database. 
EG:

```
{
 "suggestions":[
    {"value":"Item 4","data":"6","price":"0.48"},
    {"value":"Item 4","data":"6","price":"0.48"},
    {"value":"Item 4","data":"6","price":"0.48"},
    {"value":"Item 4","data":"6","price":"0.48"}
]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new suggestion each time:

```
$j = new json_prodotti;
$a = array();

foreach ($prodotti as $prd ) {
    $s = new json_suggestions;
    $s->value = $prd['name'];
    $s->data  = $prd['ID'];
    $s->price = $prd['price'];
    array_push($a,$s);
}
```

Otherwise you are modifying the same object... thats why in json_encode you get the same value for all suggestions... you are adding the same suggestion many times...